# I used "git branch -M main" inside a branch, and my original "main" disappeared

Tags: git, github, branch

I ran into a little predicament while trying to push my local repo to remote (on GitHub)...

So, I had my main branch and was developing in a second one, call it `second-branch`

I wanted to push my code to GitHub now. So I created a repo online and followed their own instructions which is:

[image: github instructions]

So I copy and pasted these commands, from inside `second-branch`

What happened is that `second-branch` is now renamed `main`...

And the original `main` is nowhere to be found. I run `git branch` and it returns only `main`, but the content of it it's what before was the content of `second-branch`

I don't know where to look for my original `main`, so any help is really appreciated

Can only pray that it's not lost lol

Thanking in advance for any consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the command:

`git reflog`

What it does is listing every instance in which a ref was updated. You should see something similar to this:

```
eff544f HEAD@{0}: commit: migrate existing content
bf871fd HEAD@{1}: commit: Add Git Reflog outline
9a4491f HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from main to git_reflog
9a4491f HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from Git_Config to main
39b159a HEAD@{4}: commit: expand on git context 
9b3aa71 HEAD@{5}: commit: more color clarification
f34388b HEAD@{6}: commit: expand on color support 
9962aed HEAD@{7}: commit: a git editor -> the Git editor
```

The first column indicates the hash of the commit.

Try to find the most recent commit of your old branch, based on the messages you see in the last column.

Once you find it, take its hash value (first column). Then:

- `git checkout <hash>`
- `git switch -c <new-branch-name>`

You should now have your old master branch on this `<new-branch-name>`

Comment: 1000 thanks! You made it super easier! I was getting into the reflog thing, but was thinking about using the hash to make a reset. Your way just gave me my branch back without touching anything else. Great!